# Make 1000s of post requests using nodejs as fast as possible

Tags: node.js

Actually, I want to Make 1000's of post requests using nodejs as fast as possible and relatively want to know that how can I achieve so I am new to nodejs that how I can do so

Can anyone give me a right path

Comment: You need to post what you have tried so far and some code to go with it

Comment: This is too generic a question to know what to do with it.  You can just put your code to make the POST requests in a `for` loop and launch 1000's of requests that way.  But there's probably more than that to a real world problem (like how many simultaneous requests a target server will be able to productively handle) so we would need to see your actual code and the target host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ⁠⁣⁡‍⁡⁠‍⁡⁣‌⁤⁠‌⁤⁠‌‍⁠⁡‍⁤⁠⁡⁠⁡⁠⁡⁠⁡⁠‍⁢⁣⁡‌⁡‍‌⁣‍‍⁣‍‌‍⁠‍⁠‌make the requests inside a loop. Take a look at the documentation for [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) and [`https`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html).

```js
const https = require("https");

for (let i=0; i<1000; i++) {
  const req = https.request({
    method: "POST",
    // Other request options
  }, resp => {
    // Handle the response, if you need
  });
  // If you need to send data, you can use `req.write()`
  req.end();
}
```